# Returning to main window when Idle-WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a system that when user doesn't do anything on it, not clicking any button, or typing text on the text box for specific length of time for example about 5 minute the system will return to it's main window?

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a limited set of relevant controls, your best bet is for each child window to have a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) member.  In your buttons' and text boxes' event handlers, reset the timer.  Your `Elapsed` handler can close the (child) window, set the focus to the parent, or whatever else you might need.